# How to Use CMS Blocks in CMS Page in Zendfox Framework?

Tags: php, html, css

**How to CMS Blocks in Zendfox Framework?
Please help me how it use in CMS Page, Templage Fiels & XML Files?**

Answer (score 2):

You can use block anywhere i.e. in layout xml, cms page, template files. The identifier key is used to call blocks.

**Using in Layout XML:** The syntax for calling CMS Block is below:

```
<view key="block-identifier-key" class="cms/block" />
```

**Using in CMS Page:** The syntax for calling CMS within the content of CMS page is below:

```
{{view key="block-identifier-key" class="cms/block"}}
```

**Using in template files:** The syntax for calling CMS Blocks in view files is below:

```
$this->getBlockContent('block-identifier-key')
```

Note: If you want to know about more using blocks - [Creating and Using Blocks](http://www.zendfox.com/documentation/creating-and-using-blocks)